# Codeigniter - Displaying individual error message for array fields

Tags: html, codeigniter, validation, validationerror

Have array of customers each with individual details.  Here is a very SIMPLE example.

`<input type="text" name="customer_names[]" />`

In codeigniter, each customer_name is required
  `$this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_names[]','Customer Names','required');`

If any of the customer names are blank, `validation_errors();` shows one message for the entire array.

How can I obtain individual error messages for that customer?

NOTE:  `echo form_error('customer_names[0]');` is what I am trying to achieve where customer_name 0  was left blank.

Comment: According to the docs, that shoul work:  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields
 What are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Form Validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) documentation, specifically the [Using Arrays as Field Names](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields) section, I think you're going to need to explicitly name your inputs 
by including the index in the name to get the `form_error()` method to work as you desire.

So in order for `form_error('customer_names[0]')` to work, there will actually have to be an input with the name `customer_names[0]`.

Comment: This worked fine for me, although I must explicitly name my fields with their respective keys in order to be useful. This [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32304264/4065407) says that CodeIgniter 3 has a feature for this.

Comment: The answer of @machineaddict is just the same to this but I did not need to specify index in the rule name.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the **same problem** with **CodeIgniter 2.1.3**. I have resolved it like this:

**The input is:**

`<input type="text" name="customer_names[0]" />

<input type="text" name="customer_names[1]" />

...`

**The form validation is:**

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_names[0]','Customer Names','required');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_names[1]','Customer Names','required');

...`

**The errors are displayed like this:**

`echo form_error('customer_names[0]');

echo form_error('customer_names[1]');

...`