# Custom validation error messages in CodeIgniter config file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter (v 3.0.0) (coming from CakePHP), and I'm trying to set custom validation error messages to one of my forms. I'm using a config file to store all my validation rules, as explained [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#how-to-save-your-rules). This is my `application/config/form_validation.php` file:

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = array(
    'appointments/signup' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'admin[name]',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Please tell us your %s',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'admin[email]',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Please enter your %s address',
                'valid_email' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
                'is_unique' => 'That email is already taken. Forgot your password?'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'admin[username]',
            'label' => 'Username',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[25]|is_unique[user_settings.username]',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Please choose a %s',
                'min_length' => '%s must me at least 4 characters long',
                'max_length' => '%s cannot exceen 25 characters',
                'is_unique' => '%s is already taken :('
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'admin[phone_number]',
            'label' => 'Phone number',
            'rules' => 'min_length[0]',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'admin[password]',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[8]',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Please choose a %s',
                'min_length' => '%s must be at least 8 characters long'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'admin[passconf]',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required|matches[admin[password]]',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Please re-type your %s',
                'matches' => '%ss do not match'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'company[company_name]',
            'label' => 'Organization\'s Name',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Please tell us your %s',
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set custom validation feedback using the `errors` array, as detailed [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-rules-using-an-array). But I still see the global default `The <field name> field is required.` message.

Is there a way to set custom validation messages in the config file, without having to edit the global default file?

Comment: I have not worked with CodeIgniter, but your field is `admin[name], admin[email], etc`... should you not just have `name, email, etc` as the field?

Comment: @AndreSantiago I don't think that's a requirement... at least it's not mentioned anywhere. The reason I have the fields named like that is because I collect two separate kinds of data: admin related data and their organization related data. The page then sends the submitted form as an ajax request in two POST variables: `$_POST['admin']` and `$_POST['company']`. The validation rules work as expected, except the custom error messages do not show.

Comment: I think that you should check [Setting Error Message](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-error-messages) section.

Comment: @Tpojka I have read the entire page on Form Validation. I'll probably have to go take that route if there's no way to keep all of my validation related stuff in one place.

Comment: Sorry for asking, did you load custom config file?

Comment: Do I have to? The [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#associating-a-controller-method-with-a-rule-group) says it's ***automatic*** if I name my rule group in the array in the format `controller_name/method_name`. Anyway, the validation works as expected when I deliberately enter invalid data, and the form submits correctly when the data is in the right format. So I must be doing things (mostly) right.

Comment: if ($this->form_validation->run('signup') == FALSE)
{
        $this->load->view('myform');
}
else
{
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
} Have you tried this when trying to validate your forms?

Comment: @RobertoNovelo According to the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#associating-a-controller-method-with-a-rule-group), if I name my validation rule groups in the format `controller/method`, I wouldn't need to manually call `$this->form_validation->run('signup')`; instead, I could simply `$this->form_validation->run()` and CodeIgniter would automatically run the validation group of the current controller's action.

Comment: I did try renaming the rule group to just `signup`, then manually called it in the controller by `$this->form_validation->run('signup')`. Still the same default messages.

Comment: Have you included the form validation library in your `autoload.php` or are you loading the library in the controller? Could you edit the question to include the relevant methods from your controller?

Answer (score 5):

Try to change the order of the keys in your array, something like this:

```
'appointments/signup' => array(
    array(
        'field' => 'admin[name]',
        'label' => 'Name',
        'errors' => array(
            'required' => 'Please tell us your %s',
        ),
        'rules' => 'required',
    )
```

The exact same problem was happening to me, and after some debugging on the core classes, I was feeling stupid enough to try this.

Looks like a bug, but I didn't go any further.

I'm using version 3.0.1.

**UPDATE**

I was wrong, if this was happening on v 3.0.0, is not happening on 3.0.1. What I described above was me making a mistake with parentheses in my array.

Everything is working as it should.

Comment: I'm also facing same problem. My version is define('CI_VERSION', '3.1.0'). Finally i follow your step ... Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

validation error messages comes from language files because each language has own error messages

I think you can change validation error messages in language files.

Comment: He's asking about custom rules, not the built in ones. Those do come from language file but should be overriden and not changed by editing core files. Probably.

Answer (score 0):

Please try use helpers under application/helpers and define your validation errors in function. Then try accessing the validation rules or use errors under application/errors. please refer https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you should put your key field within inverted commas like:

```
'field' => "admin['name']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you are using `Codeigniter 3` not any version of `Codeigniter 2.x.x`.

I was in trouble with the same issue and found that the `errors` array is available in [Codeigniter 3 version](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/) and the config rules are set in form_validation's run() method, so if you see the set_rules function in [Form_validation.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php) file you will see the 4<sup>th</sup> parameter which is `errors`

```
/**
 * Set Rules
 *
 * This function takes an array of field names and validation
 * rules as input, any custom error messages, validates the info,
 * and stores it
 *
 * @param   mixed   $field
 * @param   string  $label
 * @param   mixed   $rules
 * @param   array   $errors
 * @return  CI_Form_validation
 */
public function set_rules($field, $label = '', $rules = array(), $errors = array())
{
   .....
```

And which is not available in **2.2-stable version**, see [Form_validation.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php), and see the piece of code which shows the difference

```
/**
 * Set Rules
 *
 * This function takes an array of field names and validation
 * rules as input, validates the info, and stores it
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   mixed
 * @param   string
 * @return  void
 */
public function set_rules($field, $label = '', $rules = '')
{
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try use direct call to signup(your_func_name). 
$this->form_validation->run('signup')

**Use alternate method -** (controller_name/function_name)

```
$config = array(
   'Authenticate_user/signup' => array(
    array(
            'field' => 'firstname',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),
    array(
            'field' => 'useremail',
            'label' => 'Email ID',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|callback_check_unique_emailid' 

    ),

    array(
            'field' => 'gender',
            'label' => 'Gender',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),
     array(
            'field' => 'age',
            'label' => 'Age',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),
     array(
            'field' => 'passcode',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),
     array(
            'field' => 'confirmpasscode',
            'label' => 'Confirm Password',
            'rules' => 'required|matches[passcode]',
            'errors' => array(
            'matches[passcode]' => 'Only number is allowed'
        )
    ),
     array(
            'field' => 'usertype',
            'label' => 'User Type',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),
     array(
            'field' => 'country',
            'label' => 'Country',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),
     array(
            'field' => 'state',
            'label' => 'State',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),
    array(
            'field' => 'category',
            'label' => 'Category',
            'rules' => 'required'
    )
```

));

then call like it,

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {... }

cheers!!!